# How do i decompress a String with GZip?

Tags: vb.net

The compression works just fine, and decompression also, but what should i do if the application got closed directly after the String got compressed? How can i decompress it having the String only?

```
//Compress

Dim mem As New IO.MemoryStream
Dim gz As New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(mem, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress)
Dim sw As New IO.StreamWriter(gz)
sw.WriteLine("hello compression")
sw.Close()

Dim compressed As String = Convert.ToBase64String(mem.ToArray())

//Decompress

Dim mem2 As New IO.MemoryStream(mem.ToArray)
gz = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(mem2, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress)
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(gz)
MsgBox(sr.ReadLine)
sr.Close()

Dim decompressed As String = sr.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

When the program is closed,  the data in your memory stream is lost and not recoverable.  You'll need to save the data to a file first.

Comment: Google is your friend. StackOverflow is for solving problems people have with their code. Unfortunately it isn't a tutorial site. I found this site that shows you how to save a memory stream to file. http://net-informations.com/q/faq/memory.html